# Keycode for arrow down and open parantheses are the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

Edit: Problem is with parantheses and not with brackets as the question initially stated. Sorry for the confusion.

I am using jquery e.which on keypress to navigate table cells. But there is a problem. The e.which [keyCode] for arrow down and parantheses open '(' is 40. How can I differentiate between the two? Would this be possible?

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.js-excel-move', function(e){

    var keyPressed = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;

    var cellIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();

    if (keyPressed == 40) {
        $(this).closest('tr').next().children().eq(cellIndex).find('input').focus().select();
    }
});
```

**Update: looks like native js e.which and e.keyCode are both deprecated and can be removed anytime. Jquery e.which normalizes e.keyCode and e.charCode.**

It seems that chrome and edge do not trigger keypress event on keypress but they do on keydown.

Using keydown instead of keypress triggered the right events. Problem solved for now. Much appreciated!

Comment: I didn't think the down arrow triggered a `keypress` event(?)

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock It does. All arrow keys trigger the keypress event.

Comment: Isn't bracket key code equal 219?

Comment: What browser and OS?

Comment: @Daniel I wished it was. Searched through many stack overflow questions and many do say that 219 is the keyCode for bracket open. But on my ENG-US keyboard shift+9 (bracket open) triggers the keyCode 40. Firefox and windows 10. Checking chrome and edge right now...

Comment: Shift+9 should be an open parentheses, which returns code 57 on Windows machines.  We'll need to know what browser and operating system you're using.

Comment: Better to read the documentation for [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) first, and [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which).

Comment: @RickHitchcock 
You are right. It seems that chrome does not trigger keypress event on arrows. And neither does edge. Only Firefox so far.

Comment: Ultimately the answer will be [`.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key), but it doesn't have universal support yet.

Comment: @Teemu did not know that e.which is also deprecated. Thank you for the info.

Comment: This is an XY problem: If you're implementing a keyboard cell navigation then you *should* be using `keydown` not keypress - this would allow the user to hold down the arrow key for fast navigation rather than having to repeatably tap the key.

Comment: Please don't mix jQuery and native events. The event object in jQuery is supposed to be normalized, and any feature check in event handlers is not necessary.

Comment: @RickHitchcock keypress events do fire on chrome and edge on keydown, not on keypress.

Comment: @Teemu could you please explain what you mean with "feature check in event handlers is not necessary"?

Comment: Jquery does the check for you. All the values in in the event object passed to a jQuery event handler are already [normalized](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), you don't need to re-check them.

Comment: @RickHitchcock The problem was indeed with keypress. I should have used keydown. Now when i press shift+9, the right events are triggered. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please see also [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: @Teemu Thank you for the link and the lesson. Will keep these in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @freedomn-m if you are willing to post your comment as an answer (keydown instead of keypress), i will mark it as the answer.